# One big object or multiple small ones

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I create a map system for a roguelike type game, and i asked me what the best for tiles to have one big object that store items, terrain... or i separate them in multiple object.

An example is easier to understand :

One big class :

```
class Tile {
    unsigned char flags;
    Terrain *terrain;
    std::vector<Item> items;
    std::vector<Object> objects;
};

class Map {
    Tile tiles[100][100];
};
```

Or multiple small ones:

```
class Map {
    unsigned char flags[100][100];
    Terrain terrains[100][100];
    std::vector<Item> items[100][100];
    std::vector<Object> objects[100][100];
};
```

Is there any advantage in term of performance to load smaller object ?
Most of the time i don't need to access all the list on the same place.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Personally, I would use the first one.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to answer without studying usage model. Certainly you want to have a logical object, to collect `Tile` data, but if you iterate over certain properties multiple times, you might want to have them arranged contiguously in memory. You also might want to have multiple views, and all those properties would be shared resources... again, hard to tell. 1st one is good design for starters in most cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It entirely depends on your memory access patterns. If you find yourself iterating over all `flags`, then all `terrains`, then all `items`, then all `objects` **more frequently** than iterating over a single tile's `flags`, `terrains`, `items`, and `objects`... then the second layout might have better performance than the first one.

The only way to be sure is to profile.

---

Additionally, you can abstract the memory layout with a policy, so that you can easily change it in your tests/profiling:

```
template <typename Storage>
class Map
{
    Storage _storage;
    auto& getFlags(int x, int y);
    auto& getTerrains(int x, int y);
    auto& getItems(int x, int y);
    auto& getObjects(int x, int y);
};

struct TileStorage   { /* ... approach 1 ... */ };
struct JaggedStorage { /* ... approach 2 ... */ };
```

Comment: Ok thank you, most of the time i'm going to access only the flag array so the second solution probably better, i'm going to do some profiling as you suggest.